# Word output line by line

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, dos

I don’t understand how to make a code in assembler (tasm) that will read the input line and output each of its characters on a new line
For example:

```
Hello 
H
e
l
l
o
```

Can you help me please with line by line output

I found a code that displays a word on the screen, but I don't understand how to make it line by line

```
data segment
prompt  db  0dh,0ah,"Enter your string(7 Chars Max): $"
nam     db  8 dup(?) ; 7 plus term char $
msg1    db  0dh,0ah,"Your input: $"
sev db 7 dup(?)
data ends
code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data
START:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov dx,offset prompt
mov ah,09h
int 21h
lea si,nam
mov cx,7
et:mov ah,01
int 21h
mov [si],al
inc si
loop et
mov [si], '$'
mov dx,offset msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
lea dx,nam
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
Code ends
end Start
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Please read [ask] and make sure to ask a *specific question*.  “Can you help me please” is not a specific question.

Comment: To output the characters line by line, print in a loop one character from the string, then CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed).  You can use the [character I/O functions](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/7-character_i_o_functions.html) for this purpose.  And please write your own code.  It doesn't help you to take random uncommented code from the internet if you don't even understand what it does.  It only makes it more frustrating to help you because nobody, including you, knows what the authors of that code meant when they wrote it.